# Best solution for SQL scoring relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Im building out SQL table (SQlalchemy and Postgres) relationships and was interesting in determining if there is a better way to set up my tables.

Theres a table `Test` that can have many `Subjects` and there are many `Questions` in the subjects. I basically want to be able to input many different Tests (i.e. Test1, Test2) and have Subjects (and Questions) added. When a Test has been completed, I want to be able to update the `grade` field in Test and display a grade.

I created an Association table to help (TestSubjects). This works but when I want record the score for a Test, I have to directly update the `Questions` table, which doesnt work when I want to add more Tests.

Pseudo code looks like:

```
# Add Questions
a = Questions(name="Question1")
b = Questions(name="Question2")

# Add Subjects and add Questions to those
s1 = Subjects(name="Algebra",questions=a)
s2 = Subjects(name="History",questions=b)

# Add a group of Subjects to a Test
Test(name="test1",subjects=[s1,s2])

# Test gets sent out, completed and returned. Store the results.(And where Im struggling)
a = Questions(name="Question1",score=98)
b = Questions(name="Question2",score=76)
```

```
class Test
    __tablename__ = "test"
    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(db.String(255)
    grade = Column(db.Integer)
    subjects = relationship('Subjects', secondary='test_subjects',
                            backref=db.backref('test', lazy='dynamic'))

class Subjects
    __tablename__ = "subject"
    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(db.String(255)
    questions = relationship('Questions', backref="subject",lazy="dynamic")

class Questions
    __tablename__ = "questions"
    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(db.String(255)
    score = Column(db.Integer)
    total = Column(db.Integer)
    subject_id = Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('subject.id'))

class TestSubjects 
    __tablename__ = 'test_subjects'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    test_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('test.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    subject_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('subject.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    #question_id = Not sure if this would work?
```

I have been debating adding a third association or separating out the `score` from the `Questions` table but unsure of the best way.

Comment: I'm interested in your use-case. Do you want to calculate an average score for a test or subject, etc? If that is so, you could do all that in a single table and not waste your time spreading it across 4 to achieve the same.
consider using a table that just says "scores" and then put columns like "test_name", "subject" and "question_nr" into that.
you can still do complex queries based on this simple(r) structure, and they will possibly be less demanding than joining across tables all the time... obviously this depends on your use-case, and thats why its so important to clarify it.

Comment: @c8999c 3f964f64 Sure. My use case is I am trying to produce tests (consisting of certain subjects and questions) and store the scores when the test is complete. After completion, i want to be able to do a number of queries (average score for a Test, average score for a subject in the test, etc...). Lastly (and not actually shown here) I want to be able to track progress over time for a student.

Comment: My thinking was that If I have 2 tables (Subject and Questions), then at any time I could easily query these tables and return all registered Subjects and Questions. The third table (Test) , is a way to store the name and the Grade. I had placed them separate because I’d prefer by duplicate records in a Association table, and not in my “true source” tables. At least that is my thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're creating tables just for the heck of it

what exactly is wrong with this model here?

```
class Scores
    __tablename__ = "scores"
    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    score = Column(db.Integer)
    question = Column(db.String(255)
    subject = Column(db.String(255)
    test = Column(db.String(255)
```

instead of adding "a question" (and then reference it via its key), you can just put the name of that question in the score's question field. Same for subject and test. Basically, "tagging" the score with additional information.

You'll end up with 1 line in your table for every question for all your test. (and nothing more)

I'm not saying that this is the most sophisticated way to organize your db (it most likely isnt), but if your goal is to calculate average scores (per test / subject and / or per question), this is totally sufficient.

Now, if you later want to do these calculations on a per-student basis, you can still add a new class and have a reference to it in the scores table. (This makes sense because the Student class most likely contains a ton of information thats completely irrelevant for the score, like name & gender)

If you had 4 tables at this point already, implementing that idea will just become a lot more complicated in the future.

"Keep it simple" & YAGNI are well-known patterns in programming because it allows you to be more flexible at all times.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I agree, I would love to keep it in 1 table (max two) as you mention. But I would need another two tables anyway because I need to store all the "registered" questions and subjects beforehand. For example, when I start the program I will put in 2 subjects (Math and English) and 2 questions for each. At a later date when a Test is generated and I want both subjects in the test, I query these tables and add the referenced questions to the Test.

Additionally, If I want to add new questions and subjects then I just update these two tables. Unless theres a better way...?

Comment: Registering all the questions and subjects beforehand seems smart & organized, I see that. But it really depends on how you do this programmatically. Registering a new question is a separate task. But attaching the subject to the score can be done every time you insert new scores - a task that you do either way - and is infinitely expandable. You can still retrieve all the different subjects or questions by querying the scores table for "unique" subject fields and compile a list this way.  
    
   Scores.query.distinct(Scores.subject)

Comment: hmm that makes sense. I think ill go ahead and remove one of the tables and embed the Subject in the Questions table. Then just have a reference to the Scores table.